# Install SQL Server using PowerShell

Tags: sql-server, powershell

I have a repetitive task:

1. Download SQL Server Express edition from my own site or MS Site
2. Install SQL Server (mixed auth mode, specific collation etc etc)
3. Attach a database (compressed into a file) to my new installation
4. Create some users
5. Create file connection string according to my new installation

I know just one or two PowerShell commands but think is possible to accomplish this with it.

My question is how can I do that?

Comment: Chocolatey (https://chocolatey.org/packages?q=sql+server) has SQL Server packages and you can install that with PS. There are snippets available to attach Databases from PS: http://www.purestorage.com/blog/attachdetach-sql-server-databases-with-powershell/

Comment: Very tks. i'm going to try it.

Comment: There's also the [DSC](http://colinsalmcorner.com/post/install-and-configure-sql-server-using-powershell-dsc) option if you want to go that route.

Answer (score 2):

In short: yes.

1. From [this website](http://teusje.wordpress.com/2011/02/19/download-file-with-powershell/):

   ```
   $storageDir = $pwd
   $webclient = New-Object System.Net.WebClient
   $url = "http://your_url here"
   $file = "$storageDir\myNewFilename.jpg"
   $webclient.DownloadFile($url,$file)
   ```

   Consider throwing this on a local fileshare instead of downloading it every time.
2. The install itself is very scriptable. Check out [this MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms144259.aspx). Start small and work your way up.
3. Once you have the SQL server installed, you can connect to it and run any SQL script you want through either sqlcmd (should be installed with SQL Server) or invoke-sqlcmd (a powershell command that comes with the sqlps module). I assume that you have T-SQL for attaching the database.
4. See #3
5. To get a connection string through powershell, try the following:

   ```
   $s = new-object Microsoft.SqlServer.Managmement.Smo.Server "your_server_here";
   $s.ConnectionContext.ConnectionString;
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Steps 2 through 4 by:

- Using Desired State Configuration (DSC) to accomplish step 2. You can find an example of how to use [xSQLPs module here](http://sqlbelle.com/2015/02/09/installing-sql-server-using-powershell-desired-state-configuration-dsc/). This module contains the script for DSC with SQL Server.
- Utilize SMO for step 3-4 as this will provide better error handling and control over doing it with `sqlcmd` or `Invoke-Sqlcmd` (IMHO).

For step 5 while the example Ben gave will output a connection string, it would not be one I would suggest using for applications. I would simply go to [ConnectionStrings.com](http://www.connectionstrings.com/) and find the string format you need for your applications. Then build out a string where you just insert your instance name, user name, database, etc. You can then output that to a file at the end of the script.