# Powershell script to install Sql Server from scratch

Tags: sql, sql-server, powershell, installation, powershell-4.0

I have download the .iso file to install the SQL Server . I want to automate the process of installation on windows server using powershell script so that i can run those scripts in multiples machines.
I have searched online but didn't find any good material to do so from scratch.
I am a beginner in powershell.Can anyone provide a sample script to do so?

Tried this answer on Stackoverflow but didnt get it>
[Install SQL Server using PowerShell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25246720/install-sql-server-using-powershell)

Comment: One trick is to extract the `setup.exe` from the `iso` file and make the required changes in the `Configuration.ini` file. 
A standard `configuration.ini` file will ensure that exact same installation is present on each and every machine. I have used [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=O_BC0agK3nc&t=124s) with success.

One more way is to use the PowerShell Desired State Configuration (DSC). You can find it [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/install-windows/install-sql-server-with-powershell-desired-state-configuration?view=sql-server-2017).

Answer (score 0):

AFTER you have mounted the ISO file you can install SQL Server:

1. [From cmd passing parameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/install-windows/install-sql-server-from-the-command-prompt?view=sql-server-2017). Installing a new instance of SQL Server at the command prompt specifying the features to install and how they should be configured.
2. [From configuration file](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/install-windows/install-sql-server-using-a-configuration-file?view=sql-server-2017). SQL Server Setup provides the ability to generate a configuration file based upon the system default and run-time inputs. You can use the configuration file to deploy SQL Server throughout the enterprise with the same configuration. You can also standardize manual installations throughout the enterprise, by creating a batch file that launches Setup.exe.